# Is there a way to run a function what will self recompile if you make any changes?

Tags: salesforce-functions

I know that I can use the below commands:

```
sf run function start local
```

and

```
sf run function start container
```

But if I am making lots of small changes it is very annoying to keep killing processes and restarting them to get the latest iteration change. Unless they are meant to auto-update at which point I'll stand corrected and ask why mine seem to not.

Comment: I haven't found any such way to do this - I guess ideally we would have a 'Live Server' type functionality for this. Presumably, this could be done as a VSC extension.

Comment: yes ideally vsc would detect that you have saved something then in the most simple method auto kill the existing process and start up another